# How to check selected rows exist in database - or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application, I need to check filter matching rows do exist in database or not - how can I check that? If filter rows do exist in database, delete those rows from the database. Initially my database is empty. How can I do this?

For matching filter rows:

```
int month;
bool validMonth = int.TryParse(txtmonth.Text, out month);

int year;
bool validYear = int.TryParse(txtyear.Text, out year);         

var filteredRows = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   let date = System.DateTime.ParseExact(row.Field<string>("date"), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   where date.Month == month && date.Year == year
                   select row;

DataRow[] dr = filteredRows.ToArray();
DataTable selectedrows = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check any rows exists or not you can use

```
if(filteredRows.Any())
```